# Can I embed an atom feed in HTML5 with the <embed> tag?

Tags: html, rss, atom-feed

I'd like to be able to display information from an atom feed embedded on a html webpage.  I thought this might be possible with the HTML5 `<embed>` tag, something like:

```
    <object data="https://github.com/cboettig.atom" width="200" height="200">
    <embed src="https://github.com/cboettig.atom" width="200" height="200"> </embed>
    Loading...
    </object>
```

but no luck.  Any suggestions?  Can this be done without some [additional javascript](http://www.bloggermint.com/2012/01/easiest-way-to-embed-rssatom-feed-on-any-web-page/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work and it would embed the raw data, if the feed had an .xml extension.

I'm not sure if you want to embed raw feed data, or parsed and formatted feed data. Feed parsing must be done either client-side or server-side. If you don't want to use javascript, you can parse the feeds server-side. If my guess is right and you want to display the feed on your Jekyll powered website, there is a great feed parsing gem for Rails, called [feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra).

Comment: Many thanks! -- I installed the gem and [hacked together Jekyll ruby plugin](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/master/_plugins/feedzirra/feedzirra.rb), which creates [output like this](http://carlboettiger.info/test.html)  I don't know any ruby so this isn't very elegant -- happy for suggestions on a more sensible script.  Of course this only updates when I compile the site with Jekyll.